# How to pass a function as an argument for another function in julia?

Tags: julia

Can we pass a function as an argument of another function in julia? How does it work? Does this mean the input function is run before the calling function, or does the input function only get called if the calling function calls it specifically?

Comment: from your comments, it seems to me that partly what you're interested in is the functionality afforded by the `do` keyword. See here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/functions/#Do-Block-Syntax-for-Function-Arguments-1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of the greatest features of Julia is that you can dig out the answer to these kinda questions by yourself. Instead of making experiments and then observing the behaviors on the surface, directly asking Julia what it did under the hood is a more convenient and concise way to get the answer. Let's borrow these examples from the other two answers and ask Julia what happened via `@code_lowered`:

```
julia> f() = println("hello world")
julia> g(any_func::Function) = any_func()

#Me: hi, Julia, what happened here?
julia> @code_lowered g(f)

#Julia: hi there, this is the lowered code, anything else you want to know?
CodeInfo(:(begin 
        nothing
        return (any_func)() 
    end))
#Me: it looks like function `g` just returned `(any_func)()` and did nothing else, 
#    is it equvienlent to write `f()`?
julia> @code_typed g(f)

#Julia: yes, the codes looks the same after type inference stage: 
CodeInfo(:(begin 
        $(Expr(:inbounds, false))
        # meta: location REPL[1] f 1
        # meta: location coreio.jl println 5
        SSAValue(0) = (Core.typeassert)(Base.STDOUT, Base.IO)::IO
        # meta: pop location
        # meta: pop location
        $(Expr(:inbounds, :pop))
        return (Base.print)(SSAValue(0), "hello world", $(QuoteNode('\n')))::Void
    end))=>Void

julia> @code_typed f()
CodeInfo(:(begin 
        $(Expr(:inbounds, false))
        # meta: location coreio.jl println 5
        SSAValue(0) = (Core.typeassert)(Base.STDOUT, Base.IO)::IO
        # meta: pop location
        $(Expr(:inbounds, :pop))
        return (Base.print)(SSAValue(0), "hello world", $(QuoteNode('\n')))::Void
    end))=>Void
```

> Does this mean the input function is run before the calling function?

In this special case, it's hard to answer, the calling function `g` was optimized out by the compiler at compile time, so there was no `g` at runtime. :P Let's add some extra contents to `g`:

```
julia> g(any_func::Function) = (println("I don't wanna be optimized out!"); any_func())
g (generic function with 1 method)
julia> @code_lowered g(f)
CodeInfo(:(begin 
        nothing
        (Main.println)("I don't wanna be optimized out!")
        return (any_func)()
    end))
julia> @code_typed g(f)
CodeInfo(:(begin 
        $(Expr(:inbounds, false))
        # meta: location coreio.jl println 5
        SSAValue(0) = (Core.typeassert)(Base.STDOUT, Base.IO)::IO
        # meta: pop location
        $(Expr(:inbounds, :pop))
        (Base.print)(SSAValue(0), "I don't wanna be optimized out!", $(QuoteNode('\n')))::Void
        $(Expr(:inbounds, false))
        # meta: location REPL[2] f 1
        # meta: location coreio.jl println 5
        SSAValue(1) = (Core.typeassert)(Base.STDOUT, Base.IO)::IO
        # meta: pop location
        # meta: pop location
        $(Expr(:inbounds, :pop))
        return (Base.print)(SSAValue(1), "hello world", $(QuoteNode('\n')))::Void
    end))=>Void
```

This example shows the content of `g` would be run exactly before `f`, so the answer is YES. Follow the same pattern, it's easy to check out Liso's example:

```
julia> f = x->x+1
julia> fun(f::Function, a) = f(a)

# nothing new here, `f(9)` was called before `fun` 
# and the return value was passed to `fun` with a binding name `a`.
julia> @code_lowered fun(f, f(9))  
CodeInfo(:(begin 
        nothing
        return (f)(a)
    end))

# to verify your second question:
julia> foo(f, x) = x
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_lowered foo(f, 1)
CodeInfo(:(begin 
        nothing
        return x
    end))
```

> Does the input function only get called if the calling function calls it specifically?

So yes, the example above shows that if `f` is not called by the calling function `foo`, it will be directly optimized out.

Unlike other languages, Julia is not just a magic black box which is opaque to users, sometimes it's efficient and effective to open the box and be self-taught. BTW, There are two more stages(@code_llvm, @code_native) in Julia, you might need to dump these low-level codes for some advanced investigation, refer to Stefan's great answer in this post: [What is the difference between @code_native, @code_typed and @code_llvm in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453944/what-is-the-difference-between-code-native-code-typed-and-code-llvm-in-julia) for further details.

## UPDATE:

> what is different between these functions: g1() = f() , g2(f::Function) = f(). Results for both of them are the same, so What is different between them?

```
julia> @code_lowered g1()
CodeInfo(:(begin 
        nothing
        return (Main.f)()
    end))

julia> @code_lowered g2(f)
CodeInfo(:(begin 
        nothing
        return (f)()
    end))
```

The lowered code tell that `g1()` always returns `Main.f()`, here the `Main.f` is the `f` in the `Main` module, but `g2` returns `f()` where `f` is the function you passed to it. To make this clear, we could define `g2` as:

```
julia> g2(argumentf::Function) = argumentf()
g2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_lowered g2(f)
CodeInfo(:(begin 
        nothing
        return (argumentf)()
    end))
```

`g2` is "pass a function as an argument of another function", `g1` can be considered as an alias for `Main.f`. Does this make sense to you? @ReD

Answer (score 4):

Julia has always supported [first-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) as well as [higher-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) functions. This means that yes, functions can be arguments to other functions. In addition, the language has also always had support for [anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) and [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

Originally, calling functions that were passed into other functions came with a  performance penalty. However, as of v0.5, this is no longer an issue, and functions you pass into other functions as arguments will run just as quickly as functions from base julia. There is more reading on this [here](https://julialang.org/blog/2016/10/julia-0.5-highlights).

A simple example of passing functions follows:

```
julia> f() = println("hello world") #Define a simple function f
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g(any_func::Function) = any_func() #Define a function g that accepts any function as input and then calls that function
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g(f) #Call g with f as the input
hello world
```

What is happening here is that I build a function `f` in the first line, which, when called via `f()`, will print "hello world". In the second line I build a function `g` which accepts *any function* as input, and then calls that function. In the third line, I call my function `g` using my function `f` as input, and `g` then runs the function `f`, which, in this case, will print "hello world".

The example above may seem trite, but in more complicated scenarios, being able to pass functions around like this is *incredibly* useful.

As the other answerer points out, base julia exploits this feature with many native functions that accept other functions (including anonymous functions) as input, such as `map`, `filter`, etc.

*Most readers can stop here. What follows is only relevant to those who use `eval` a lot...*

There is one exception to the above, which the average user is unlikely to ever encounter: If a function is built by parsing and evaluating a string at runtime, and this function is called during the same runtime, then the call will fail with an error message that will say something about "world age". What is actually happening here is that because the function has been created at runtime, the compiler does not have an opportunity to reason about the behaviour of the function, e.g. input and output types, and so it "prefers" not to call it. Nonetheless, if you really want to you can get around this by calling it via the `Base.invokelatest` method, but this means the function call will not be type-stable. Basically, unless you really know what you're doing, you should avoid messing around with this.

Comment: what is different between these functions: `g1() = f() ` , `g2(f::Function) = f()` . Results for both of them are the same, so What is different between them?

Comment: @ReD I've added a longer explanation of the code. Does that help?

Comment: @ReD have you checked out my answer? you can dump the lowered code to find the differences. I've updated this example in my post.

Answer (score 3):

map is one example where function is used as parameter

```
# you could define function
julia> f = x->x+1

# and use it (f mapped to array elements) ->
julia> map(f, [1, 2, 3])
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4
```

f is not called before using it in map!

**edit (reaction to comment bellow):**

to symbol f is mapped function object (it is method what to do with parameters)  and this symbol could be called in fun.

```
# fun(ny) example 
julia> function fun(f::Function, a)
      return f(a)  
   end
fun (generic function with 1 method)

# using f defined above
julia> fun(f, 10)
11

# or anonymous function defined in place:
julia> fun(x->x^2, 10)
100
```

And maybe more complicated example could be understandable too. f is called one time before fun execution (to calculate parameter a) and one time in fun function body:

```
julia> fun(f, f(9))
11
```

Comment: I saw something like this: `function fun(f::Function....)` I want to know how does it work